# How to pass bash variable as a string not array to a scala file

Tags: bash, scala, terminal, gitlab-ci

```
export str_opt="$(cat bi_sureyield_clicks_v.sql|tr '\n' ' ')"
sbt "run $str_opt"
```

I have this code in gitlab-ci.yml file. I want to do something when a sql file is commited in the repo.And since the sql file as \n init I truncate it and then send it to the scala project using sbt run but in the code I do something like

```
object printtest {
    def main(args:Array[String]):Unit = {
        println("HELLO WORLD SCALA" + args.length)
        args.foreach{println}
    }
}
```

and it shows length >1. It takes \n or space as a delimeter for a new string. How do I get it as a single string in scala so I can use the query and do something with it. 
I don't want to write code on Scala end. Is it possible using bash or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add escaped double-quotes within the double-quotes, like this:

```
sbt "run \"$str_opt\""
```

Comment: do you also know how to get **A sql** file which is committed to the repo and use that instead of hardcoded `export str_opt="$(cat bi_sureyield_clicks_v.sql|tr '\n' ' ')"`

Comment: or should I use a dir in the repo and always commit file in that dir and read the file * from that directory? or something like that.